# Exrin InjectionProxy InstanceType meaning and uses

Tags: exrin

When looking through the main app bootstrapper, the `InjectionProxy` is used to register instances and interfaces. I noticed that interfaces can be registered as `InstanceType.SingleInstance` (done for the database in the Tesla app) or `InstanceType.EachResolve`. Further delving of the `InjectionProxy` code shows that instances are always `SingleInstance`.

What is the difference between `SingleInstance` and `EachResolve`, why would I choose my interfaces to be one or the other, and why are instances always set to be `SingleIstance`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SingleInstance** means that it will only ever create one copy of the class, for use in anything that requests it.

**EachResolve**, means that each class that has this interface injected into it, will get a new instance of the interface.

It depends on what you want for your app. In most cases, SingleInstance is what you want, but EachResolve is there incase your situation requires a new instance, instead of the same one used throughout your app.